# How to get synchronous HTTP response?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I write a class to handle the request to web. And it has a method which is using `WebClient` actually to do the main job. When the `DownloadStringCompleted` method has been done, I want to return the value of the response.

I want to use that like this:

```
// the pubTimeLine() method returns the value 
// of the request to the web using WebClient      
textBlock1.DataContext = wp.pubTimeLine(url);
```

How to make it? Or how to get the synchronous response of HTTP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never make synchronous network calls, it will freeze up your UI (and therefore your phone) which is a very bad user experience.

Instead do it asynchronously, something like:

```
wp.pubTimeLine(url, result => textBlock1.DataContext = result);
```

Where the second parameter is a lambda expression containing the callback that is called when the pubTimeLine method is done executing asynchronously.

Comment: Perhaps it is a stupid question,but i dont know how it works?Can you explain more?Or give me a study link~thanks~

Comment: Here's a post on a similar subject I wrote a while back: http://justinmchase.com/post/2008/04/23/Thinking-Async-1-Asynchronous-Data-Access-in-Silverlight-20.aspx

Comment: Also the secret sauce is in something called a Lambda Expression: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx Also try reading up on "Continuation Passing Style".

Comment: You can certainly make synchronous network calls if you do it on a worker thread.  The fact that MS chose to take this option away from WP7 developers is an act of insufferable hand-holding.

Comment: @tempy: I disagree. There is no scenario where asynchronous calls are not better. There is no good reason to enable that scenario. Similar to javascript, there is no mechanism to do this intentionally. It's a little bit harder conceptually if you're used to synchronous network programming but it's a lot easier in the sense that you don't have to get to the end and realize it sucks and start all over again, doing it async the second time.

Comment: @justin.m.chase "no scenario"? Only the Sith deal in absolutes.