# How to get a synchronous HTTP response

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to call one restful api synchronously. I want to know how can I hit service api synchronously? Is it possible to call api synchronously?

Comment: Can you give us a scenario in which it's needed to you? Any code you have so far? The answer to your question is "yes", btw.

Comment: @igrali: I want to hit  payment api and want to lock the screen (display loding screen) till the payment api response comes. Once response come, based on that want to call another webservice.

Comment: This sounds like asynchronous scenario. Call first api -> show loading screen -> when you receive async callback, call the next api call -> when the second call returns, remove loading screen.

Comment: @Igrali: Thanks for your answer. It seems like asynchronous call. But can you tell me how can I add loading screen on one page that will cover whole page section.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get synchronous HTTP response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939735/how-to-get-synchronous-http-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a synchronous call for your scenario. All you need is to handle the incoming response, and the asynchronous model does that perfectly.

Assuming that you are working with WebClient (easily adapted to any scenario):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s,e) =>
{
     if (e.Result == "Paid")
        LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
};
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://somerestapi.out.there"));
LoadingScreen.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can we add multiple screen on one page?. is it possible to add multiple screen on one page?

Comment: You are looking for popups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456394.aspx

Comment: Once again thanks for your answer. One more thing can you tell me when, why and how we should implement usercontrol in your windows app.

Comment: That solely depends on the scenarios you plan on implementing. You might want to start here: http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/User-Control-vs-Custom-Control-in-Silverlight-for-WP7